# Modify PDF generated on server in JavaScript before displaying

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, pdf, tcpdf

I'm facing an interesting problem right now: I want to modify a PDF file generated on the server (using TCPDF and Symfony2) on the client before displaying it.

Why? The PDF will contain some semi-sensitive information and our customers would probably be happy to hear that this info never leaves their machines. (I'm aware that HTTPS is considered pretty much safe enough, this is more of a luxury issue to assure our customers that their data is safe.)

This is how far I got: Use placeholders on the PDF, save it as a String and retrieve it via AJAX, replace the placeholders with the local data, and convert the string to Base64. The real issue is getting the file to the user.

A lot of people recommend using the HTML5 "download" Attribute and clicking a hidden link with it, that method does not work on Safari or older versions of IE though. Data URIs are another option, but beyond a certain complexity the base64 string just gets too long and the browser freezes trying to display it in the address field. I also looked at libraries like Downloadify.js, FileSaver.js etc. but none of these seem widely supported (or rely on flash, which I would love to avoid).

I'm very open to suggestions as to what else I could try, or even someone telling me why what I'm trying to do is wholly unnecessary.

Comment: Rather than generating a PDF server-side, getting it to the client, modifying it, etc., perhaps consider sending the contents you want made into a PDF to the client, letting the client make modifications, and then create the PDF on the client-side using a library like jsPDF (https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).